# passar varios parametros pro ireport

Tags: java, ireport

No meu programa Java seleciono uma lista de valores e queria passar essa lista para o iReport como parâmetro. Essa parâmetro seria utilizado na consulta SQL: 
SELECT ... 
FROM ... 
WHERE ... IN($P{lista})

quando eu passo um codigo só ele funciona como where= $P{codigo}

mas eu quero passar varios codigos ao mesmo tempo como faço isso?

eu tentei 
List codigos = new ArrayList();
        codigos.add(1);
        codigos.add(2);
        codigos.add(3);

```
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("codigo", codigos);
```

mas nao funcionou

tentei passar uma string tipo "1,2,3" e tb nao funcionou